# Make all buckets have the same height with display flex

Tags: css, flexbox

Hi there can someone help me achieve all the buckets to have the same height with flex display? The top row has a different height than the lower row.
Here is the CSS i am using. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej2Ol.jpg

.outer-buckets is the parent container around all of the buckets.

.bucket is the individual buckets

CSS:

```
.new-template-inner .outer-buckets {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
}
.new-template-inner .outer-buckets .bucket {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Grid layout would be great instead of flexbox in this case.

Comment: It's not the row that's bigger. It's the "bucket" that has 2 lines of text. That's why the row seems to have bigger height, and the other 2 "buckets" grow to fit the height of the row.
I don't see a problem here. If the text were to be even longer, you'd want the "buckets" to adapt and to be the same height